# pqxx: broken_connection on trying to connect to posgres db

Tags: postgresql, psql, libpqxx

I have this problem trying to connect to the local postrgres databases. Until now i succeeded to connect to the same databases using jdbc or working directly in PGAdmin, this error happens when i try to connect using pqxx library or from shell:

pqxx code:

```
#include <pqxx/connection.hxx>

int main(){
    pqxx::connection conn("user=postgres port=5432 dbname=pqxx-test password=postgres");
    return 0;
}
```

or from shell, as user postgres:

```
psql pqxx-test
```

both the cases raise this error:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server
>   running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Searching for the solution i think i understood i have to edit pq_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files in order to connect in these ways, but in pg_hba.conf is already set:

> local all all md5

and in postgresql.conf

> listen_addresses='*'

And by the way, i'm not even able to edit these files because of a problem with the viminfo, but maybe this is another problem..

Can anyone help me?

edit:
using PostgreSQL 9.6.2
on Ubuntu 14.04

**edit**:

as postgres user, if i ask for the postgre version using:
psql -V

> the result is **9.6.2**

but looking at the file system hierarchy, all conf file are inside this folder

> /opt/PostreSQL/**9.4**/data/

can that be the problem?

Comment: have you tried `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5`? Did you also reload the pg_hba? `select pg_reload_conf()`

Comment: yes, but nothing changed

Comment: I edited my question, maybe a version missmatch problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a mix of client-side postgresql 9.6 configured for the ubuntu FS layout and a postgresql server 9.4 presumably downloaded from EntrepriseDB (and installed under `/opt/PostgreSQL`) using its own layout.

Assuming that the postgresql is running, the simplest solution is to add `host=localhost` to your connection string, so that it will use a TCP connection instead of the Unix domain socket `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` that does not exist because of the mismatch.

Comment: That solves my problem! Thank you! However i don't remember how i got to this strange mix of configurations, but do you suggest to clean it and keep just one version with its own layout? i mean, am i going to have problems for example connecting to remote dbs?

Comment: @Todde: yes, I'd suggest to use Ubuntu packages. For one thing they would benefit of automated updates with apt.